# ¿Como hago un Trigger que envie datos especificos y no reciba datos especificos de una tabla a otra en SQL server 2019?

Tags: sql

**EJ:** Todo elemento que no sea Tela y Yarns de la tabla "OrgPro" se va a "Purc_Be" es todo todo, y los datos se van a otra base de datos en el mismo servidor y no debe de ser por método `UPDATE` y cuando un nuevo elemento se incluya a la tabla, que se ingrese en el FabComponent t pero  cualquiera que no sea "Tela", y "Yarns" se va a "Purc_be (Purc_be es la otra tabla en otra base de datos) (Tela y Yarns son dos tablas de la base de datos OrgPro que corresponden a los campos Cat 1 y Cat 2 respectivamente y además hay mas tablas en esta bd y quiero que todos se los datos se vallan mientras no sean de Cat1 y Cat 2 y la bd  debe de recibir los datos en diferentes tablas como ejemplo Product name se va a Componenetes de  la tabla basicamente es migrar todos los datos a otra tabla primero de OrgPro a Purc_be mientras no sean Tela y Yarns de las tablas Cat1 y Cat 2, luego si alguien quiere volver a ingresar datos a la tabla mientras no sean Tela y Yarns se van a FabComp t y cualquiera que no sea "Yarns" se va a Purc_be)

La posible solución con programación: lo que puedo hacer sin utilizar un Update es utilizar un

```
while  var1 =! de "Tela" y Var 2 =! de Yarns 
        INSERT into Purc_be.componenetes el contenido de Product_name
        INSERT into Purc_be.cata el contenido de Category2
        INSERT into Purc_be.catasub el contenido de Category1
```

y lo mismo para la otra Bd llamada FabComponents t
el problema es que no se la sintaxis del trigger para hacerlo completo en SQL server 2019 y como se haría?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).
La opción editar está justo bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas!

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. Podrias tratar de explicar mejor tu problema? la sintaxis de un trigger esta en la documentacion de la base de datos...

Comment: Mira la sintaxis de un trigger de sql server es bastante diferente a la que yo conozco es esta  CREATE TRIGGER <Schema_Name, sysname, Schema_Name>.<Trigger_Name, sysname, Trigger_Name> 
   ON  <Schema_Name, sysname, Schema_Name>.<Table_Name, sysname, Table_Name> 
   AFTER <Data_Modification_Statements, , INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE>
AS 
BEGIN
 -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
 -- interfering with SELECT statements.
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for trigger here

END
GO

Comment: Y la verdad se me hace dificil entender cada una parte del codigo que antes era mas simple

Comment: Mira este documento y si tienes problemas con la sintaxis, edita la pregunta y vemos hasta donde has llegado. [Trigger After Insert](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2020/04/12/trigger-que-es-como-se-hace-y-como-funciona-after-for-insert/). Luego igual es el de [Update](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2020/04/15/trigger-que-es-como-se-hace-y-como-funciona-after-for-update/). Y según vayas avanzando hay más posibilidades.